# HP proliant dl320 g6: all DIMM lights red, long beeping sound & internal health led red

Tags: hp-proliant

I am working on a server with the ff. issues
1. all dimm lights are red
2. the internal health led is red
3. the server gives of long beeping sounds

I have checked the CPU, power supply unit, memory and hard disk with another server that is healthy and they are ok. I am unable to log into the ILO2 configured on the server.

Can anybody help with suggestions to resolve the issue?

Comment: If you have physical access to the server and can count the number of long and short beeps this can give you some breadcrumbs, occasionally.  You can look up the tones on the HP website and perhaps get a rough idea of the issue.  Perhaps your DIMM slots are bad or even the memory.  Surprised you haven't called HP support.

Answer (score 2):

Your system board is probably dead. Please connect to the ILO2 port on the server and record the messages you see in the IML log. They will specify that your actual problem is.

Comment: Since I am not able to log into the ILO, is it possible to check the IML log?

Comment: Why can't you reach the ILO?

Comment: If all the components work in other systems, that should tell you either the onboard diag unit is dead (which requires a motherboard replacement) or the motherboard is dead (which also requires a motherboard replacement...)

Comment: @ewwhite. There is another server which is healthy. I log into it just the way I do for the faulty one changing the default gateway and ip address accordingly. I am able to log into the healthy one but not the faulty one.

Comment: @PetuniaHaddock Then the motherboard is probably dead.

Comment: If the motherboard is faulty is it ok to purchase a used one online from Amazon, ebay etc

Comment: @PetuniaHaddock I don't know! Call HP support.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. What causes the motherboard to fail this way?

Comment: @PetuniaHaddock That is an answer that is nearly impossible to answer. The reasons can be a single dust particle that shorted something, to a capacitor blowing up due to a current spike. Even something as ESD can kill it, even when unplugged. Even the power supply can have a hickup and send 6v accross the 5v connection. There are endless possibilities! Check everything, al the way down to jumpers (if the board has them).

Comment: I am suspecting that the reason we are not able to log into ILO is because the memory was cleared using the maintenance switch. Is there anything that can be done to salvage the situation?

Comment: @PetuniaHaddock ***Call HP***.